# Como reiniciar loop após erro em request

Tags: python, python-requests

Estou criando um bot no telegram para utilizar uma API, que quando envio um link, ela retorna o link reduzido. O problema é que se eu mandar algo que não seja um link, o bot vai dar erro e fechar, pensei em algum "IF", para o erro 400, que é o "Bad Request" que retorna quando ele procura um link e não acha.

Qual seria o jeito para reiniciar o processo?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["fastshop"])
def fastshop(mensagem):
        sent_msg = bot.send_message(mensagem.chat.id, "Olá, qual link quer converter?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent_msg, pega_link)
def pega_link(mensagem):
    link = mensagem.text     

    
    url = ''
    # Dados para acessar a web service

    Bodys = json.dumps({
    "advertiserId": ,
    "destinationUrl": link,
    "shorten": True
    })

    headers = {
        'Authorization': '',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=Bodys)

    print(response.status_code)
    print(response)

    RetornoLink = response.json()

    x_link = (format(RetornoLink['shortUrl']))
    bot.reply_to(mensagem, x_link)
```

Comment: não seria só tratar o trecho em que pode ocorrer o problema com um `try except`?

Comment: É uma boa, mas como eu definiria o erro?

Comment: erro 400 ou 422. Fica à seu critério.

Comment: Se não sabe que tipo de status vai retornar use o `if`nesse caso não ter erros ele passa mas em algum momento ocorrer algo no `else` pode tratar da forma que precisa.  `if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok: """teu códido""" else: continue`